# Sub-modules of free modules: twisting question a little

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The following theorems appear many places in books and on this site also.

> Sub-modules of a free module are free, provided the ring of scalars is P.I.D.
>
> If $R$ is not P.I.D. then sub-module of a free $R$-module  *may not be* free.

I have gone through the proof of theorem as well as counterexample. But my next question comes from these two facts:

> Let  $M$ is an $R$-module (and assume that $M$ *has* proper sub-modules). If $R$ is not a P.I.D., then is it necessary that there *exists* a sub-module of $M$ which is not free?

Comment: My gut says maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If $M$ is not free, then the result is trivial.

Assume that $M$ is free.  Then $M$ contains a copy of $R$, so it is sufficient to prove the claim for $R$.

Since $R$ is not a PID, then either it contains a non-principal ideal, or it is not an integral domain.  In the latter case, let $a$ be a zero-divisor; then the submodule of $R$ generated by $a$ is not free.

Finally, assume that $R$ is an integral domain, and let $I$ be a non-principal ideal of $R$.  If $I$ were a free $R$-module, then it would admit a basis $(x_j)_{j\in J}$, with $J$ a set containing at least two elements.  But then, for any $i\neq j$ in $J$, we would have
$$ x_ix_j - x_jx_i = 0, $$
contradicting the linear independence of $x_i$ and $x_j$.  Thus $I$ is not a free module.